# Bash(Linux) Shell Script to zip the files older than 30 days

Tags: zip

**Search for *.aud files in a directory for past 30 days and zip it; remove all those files
 after successful zip

I used following but it is not removing the files after zip

find . -mtime -30 | xargs tar --no-recursion -czf Audit_Mar_2011.tgz **

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin.bash
#quick and dirty:
FILES=`find . -mtime -30 | xargs`
tar --no-recursion -czf Audit_Mar_2011.tgz "${FILES}"
rm -rf "${FILES}"
```

Comment: "${FILES}" is spelt incorrectly. bash is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! Just stopped holding shift too soon.